# Question on finitely generated algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

While reading Reid's "Introduction to Algebraic Geometry", I came across the following passage:

> "A finitely generated $k$-algebra is a ring of the form $A = k[a_1,\cdots,a_n]$, so that $A$ is generated as a
>   ring by $k$ and $a_1, \cdots , a_n$; clearly, every such ring is isomorphic to a quotient of the polynomial ring,
>   $A =
> k[X_1, \cdots ,X_n]/I$"

My question is: **why must such ring be isomorphic to a ring of the form $k[X_1, \cdots ,X_n]/I$?**

Comment: The short answer is "because of the evaluation homomorphism", which has an ideal $I$ as its kernel.

Comment: Of course, silly me. Thank you!

Comment: Now your job is to write up the Answer with more detail, or find a previous Question that we can claim this duplicates!

Comment: Thank you for the link, I added an answer with the reference.

Answer (score 1):

As user hardmath pointed out in the comments, this easily follows from the evaluation homomorphism. For more details, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35403/finitely-generated-k-algebra-and-polynomial-ring).